# Pylons "global name 'c' is not defined"

Tags: python, pylons, genshi

i had setup Pylons v0.9.7, and created a project using genshi.
I tried to code an easy test case, but it is not working.

code: member.py

```
coding: utf-8 
import logging import foo.model

from foo.lib.base import *

log = logging.getLogger(__name__)

class MemberController(BaseController):

    def index(self):
        c.title="title"
        c.mes="message"
        return render('test.html')
```

code: test.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns:py="http://genshi.edgewall.org/"
      lang="ja">
    <head>
        <title>${c.title}</title>
    </head>
<body>
    <p>${c.mes}</p>
</body>
</html>
```

and Error message(on log)

```
Error - <type 'exceptions.NameError'>: global name 'c' is not defined
```

Please help me find the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    c.title="title"
```

requires name `c` to be defined (globally or locally).  You never define **anything** named `c`.

So, define a suitable name `c` (one where attribute `title` can be set!) before you assign anything to `c.title`!

Next hint: `from pylons import tmpl_context as c` -- you didn't *do* that `from ... import ... as`, did you now?-)

Comment: Giving is a light as for the hint. 
I have your book(python CookBook)!
I am very honored. 
Hereafter, it tries again.

Comment: Ahhh! it worked! thanks Alex!
i understand "C was tmpl_context".
I wish sincerely to express our gratitude.